# Jinja2 not working in newsletter.html

Tags: python, html, jinja2, templating

I have this function which gets data from an API and then uses Jinja2 to insert this data into an HTML file. I want this data to show up in my newsletter.html and be sent as an email. Everything works fine apart from
this happening:

[image]

Here are some relevant snippets:

Getting the data as list and templating with Jinja:

```
# movie_finder.py

movie_list = []
for item in now_playing['results']:
    if genre_id in item['genre_ids']:
        movie_list.append(item['original_title'])

print movie_list

# Create jinja2 environment
try:
    env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('movie_finder', 'templates'))
    template = env.get_template('newsletter.html')
    rend = template.render(info=movie_list)
    print "Templating successful"
except:
    print "Templating fail"
    return "Templating fail"



find_movies_with_genre(API_KEY, 878)
```

In the script that sends the email (which otherwise works fine), I simply do:

```
from scifi_finder import find_movies_with_genre
```

Template:

```html
<!--  Newsletter template by https://github.com/derekpunsalan/-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

    <!-- For development, pass document through inliner -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple.css">

    <style type="text/css">
```

output `print movie_list`:

```
[u'Thor: Ragnarok', u'Blade Runner 2049', u'War for the Planet of the Apes', u'Geostorm']
```

Comment: Please also include the template file in your question, could be the issue is there and it is relevant to get the full picture of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the variables correctly when calling `render()`, here is what you are doing:

```
template.render(info=movie_list)
```

You are passing a variable `info`, yet in your template, you are referring to `movie_list`:

```
{% for item in movie_list %}
  {{ item[0] }}
  {{ item[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will not work, you need to refer to the variable you are passing, personally I prefer it this way:

```
template.render(movie_list=movie_list)
```

...and in template...

```
{% for item in movie_list %}
  {{ item[0] }}
  {{ item[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

...as you have it already. You could just as well use...

```
{% for item in info %}
  {{ item[0] }}
  {{ item[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

...in your template and keep your function call as it is, but personally I find the first variant less confusing when I read it again weeks later.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Sadly the output is still the same!

Comment: @MartaP. Can you include the full template in your question? And maybe the output from your `print movie_list` statement?